# Wordpress: "Warning: Illegal string offset" in multiple places

Tags: php, wordpress, error-handling, syntax-error

Hopefully, you guys can help me here. What's going on with these issues in my WordPress install, see the errors and referenced code block.

Errors:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'domain' in /home/customer/www/xxxxxxxx.xxx/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 583

Warning: Illegal string offset 'context' in /home/customer/www/xxxxxxxx.xxx/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 587

Warning: Illegal string offset 'singular' in /home/customer/www/xxxxxxxx.xxx/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 588

Warning: Illegal string offset 'plural' in /home/customer/www/xxxxxxxx.xxx/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 588

Warning: Illegal string offset 'context' in /home/customer/www/xxxxxxxx.xxx/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 588

Warning: Illegal string offset 'domain' in /home/customer/www/xxxxxxxx.xxx/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 583

Warning: Illegal string offset 'context' in /home/customer/www/xxxxxxxx.xxx/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 587

Warning: Illegal string offset 'singular' in /home/customer/www/xxxxxxxx.xxx/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 588

Warning: Illegal string offset 'plural' in /home/customer/www/xxxxxxxx.xxx/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 588

Warning: Illegal string offset 'context' in /home/customer/www/xxxxxxxx.xxx/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 588
```

Code:

```
function translate_nooped_plural( $nooped_plural, $count, $domain = 'default' ) {
    if ( $nooped_plural['domain'] ) {
        $domain = $nooped_plural['domain'];
    }

    if ( $nooped_plural['context'] ) {
        return _nx( $nooped_plural['singular'], $nooped_plural['plural'], $count, $nooped_plural['context'], $domain );
    } else {
        return _n( $nooped_plural['singular'], $nooped_plural['plural'], $count, $domain );
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `if ( $nooped_plural['context'] )` to `if ( isset($nooped_plural['context']) )`

Comment: Unfortunately still providing the following errors:
```Warning: Illegal string offset 'domain' in /home/customer/www/xxx.xxx/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 583

Warning: Illegal string offset 'singular' in /home/customer/www/xxx.xxx/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 590

Warning: Illegal string offset 'plural' in /home/customer/www/xxx.xxx/public_html/wp-includes/l10n.php on line 590```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Warning: Illegal string offset 'something'` message means that you're trying to access the value of `$someVar['something']` but it doesn't exist.

To avoid it, you should always use `isset($someVar['something'])` to check if the index exists (or not) in the given variable.

Comment: Thanks for that, I went and changed all outstanding variables within that section without the 'isset' keyword to include that.